How to create wildcard index in monodb atlas search index?
I am using MongoDB Atlas, and my data is stored like this:

  {"abc": "123"},

  {"def": "456"}

]


Now, I want to create a search index on this collection with my custom analyzer. Here's what I tried:

{

  "mappings": {

    "dynamic": false,

    "fields": {

      "*": [

        {

          "type": "string",

          "analyzer": "keywordLowerer",

          "searchAnalyzer": "standardLowerer"

        }

      ]

    },

    "analyzers": [

      {

        "name": "standardLowerer",

        "tokenizer": {

          "type": "standard"

        },

        "tokenFilters": [

          {

            "type": "lowercase"

          }

        ]

      }

    ]

  }

}


However, it is not working.
What I Tried:
Created a search index with the above configuration in MongoDB Atlas.
Used dynamic: false and mapped all fields (*) to use the keywordLowerer analyzer for indexing and standardLowerer for search.
What I Expected:
The search index to be created successfully with the custom analyzers and wildcard field.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
